# Fantasy novel where an ax man fights an older sword master

Tags: story-identification, novel, sword-and-sorcery

I'm looking for a fantasy novel that I read I think in the early '80s. There's one fantastic scene where an ax-wielding young prodigy is chasing the evil villain down an escape tunnel, and comes into conflict with an aging swordmaster defending the villain, because he doesn't realize he's a villain. Tragically, the swordmaster kills the ax-wielder. I think it was like the second book in a series?

I tried asking a chatbot and it pointed me to [*Skilgannon*](https://davidgemmell.fandom.com/wiki/Skilgannon) and [*Druss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Chronicles_of_Druss_the_Legend), but that's not correct. It also said that the ax wielder's name is Caderly and the Swordmaster's name is Kryll, but searching on those names doesn't get me the book I'm looking for.

Comment: My own experience of using Bard to identify stories is that it just makes up random stories that don't exist. You don't say which chatbot you used, but I doubt anything it said is reliable.

Comment: Cadderly is the main character from these books;  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cleric_Quintet. That being said, these don't match your question and it's far more likely that this is a ChatGPT '[hallucination](https://bernardmarr.com/chatgpt-what-are-hallucinations-and-why-are-they-a-problem-for-ai-systems/)_'

Comment: I'm definitely coming to the conclusion that ChatGPT just took my description and filled in some names from a similar book plot.

Comment: @DavidC - if you don't remember those details, I'd focus on what you do remember, rather than chasing ghosts

Comment: That vaguely rings a bell, is it possibly something from a Kane story by Karl Edward Wagner?